# How to show data from multiple lists on one calender view

Tags: sharepoint-2007, moss

Is there any way in which I can combine the data from multiple lists and show it on single calender View?

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 0):

YEs there is, by creating a webpart in sharepoint designer that uses a CAML query to get all items of type event from the site and use the result as a datasource for calendar.

This blog post does what you want exactly: [Creating SharePoint global calendar](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/01/24/creating-sharepoint-global-calendar.aspx) by Gunnar Peipman.